# How do i validate this requirements using RegEx

Tags: javascript

How do i validate this requirements using regular expression in Javascript ?

For Telephone Number the pattern should be:
    3 digits followed by a dash (–) which is also followed by 4 digits. As an example 123-1234 is a valid phone number.

For PO Box the pattern should be:
    2 characters from alphabet (A to Z) case sensitive followed by 3 digits from (0 to 9)
                Or
                    5 digits (from 0 to 9)

As an example: NY090 or 90392 both are valid.

For Password the pattern should be:
        6 to 8 characters as digits (0 to 9) and/or/(or a mixture) alphabet (A to Z) followed by 3 digits from (0 to 9)
                        As an example:  ABCDEF123, ABCDEFG123,  A1B1CD123 all are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regular expressions (`re`):

- Telephone: `/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/`
- PO Box: `/^[A-Z0-9]{2}\d{3}$/`
- Password: `/^[A-Z0-9]{6,8}\d{3}$/`

in the format:

`re.test(yourstringhere)`

Answer (score 1):

for the phone number:
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}

for the PO box:
(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})|([0-9]{5}))

for the password:
[A-Z,0-9]{6,8}[0-9]{3}

Answer (score 1):

These regular expressions should hold true throughout my testing:

- Telephone: `^\d{3}[-]\d{4}$` (exactly 3 digits (`\d`), a `-`, and then exactly 4 digits)
- PO Box: `^(\d{2}|[A-Z]{2})\d{3}$` (Two digits OR two letters between a-z or A-Z and then exactly three digits - note that \w does not work for letters as \w also includes underscores and digits)
- Password: `^[A-Z0-9]{6,8}\d{3}$` (6-8 characters between (a-z, A-Z, 0-9), followed by three digits)

Comment: Thank you @Mike. good explanation.. :) i tried using \w for validating po box... now i know my mistake... Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If you have enough reputation (I think it's 15??), feel free to upvote if the explanations helped :D